# If $f\circ f\circ g\circ g\circ f\circ f$ is invertible, so is $g$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f\circ f\circ g\circ g\circ f\circ f$ be invertible (i.e., have left and right inverse functions).
>
> Prove $g$ is invertible as well.

I would appreciate it if you helped me.

Comment: No any further information as for $f$.

Comment: Hints: use (repeatedly) (1) If $f\circ g$ is injective then $g$ is injective; (2) if $g\circ f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective; (3) $f$ is inverible iff it is injective and surjective. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will denote $f^{2}=f\circ f$ and similarly for $g^2$. I would also
write $fg$ for $f\circ g$ etc' .

$f^{2}g^{2}f^{2}$ is invertible hence it is $1-1$ and onto. We know
that if a composition $f_{1}\circ f_{2}$ is $1-1$ then so must be
$f_{2}$ and if the composition is onto than so is $f_{1}$.

Using those facts for our case we get that 
$$
f(fg^{2}f^{2})
$$

is onto hence so is $f$ . on the other hand 
$$
(f^{2}g^{2}f)f
$$

is $1-1$ and so must be $f$ . We conclude $f$ is invertible.

Now - multiplying by an invertible function doesn't change the invertability
of what we multiply by so 
$$
f^{-1}f^{-1}(f^{2}g^{2}f^{2})f^{-1}f^{-1}=g^{2}
$$

is also invertible.

Now 
$$
g\circ g
$$

is $1-1$ and onto. Setting $f_{1}=f_{2}=g$ we get that $g$ is also
$1-1$ and onto, completing the proof.

Answer (score 2):

In general and not difficult to prove: if $u\circ v$ is a bijection then $u$ is surjective and
$v$ is injective.

Applying that here we find that $f$ is surjective and injective,
hence is a bijection.

Then $g\circ g=f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ f\circ f\circ g\circ g\circ f\circ f\circ f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$
is - as composition of bijections - also a bijection, and again we
can apply the rule to find this time that $g$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h$ be the inverse of $k := f\circ f \circ g \circ g \circ f \circ f$. Then $h \circ k = id = k \circ h$, which implies $u\circ f = id = f \circ v$, where $u = h \circ f \circ f \circ g \circ g \circ f$ and $v = f\circ g \circ g \circ f \circ f \circ h$. Since $u$ is a left inverse of $f$, $f$ is $1-1$; since $v$ is a right inverse of $f$, $f$ is onto. Therefore, $f$ is invertible. Now $g\circ g$, being the composition of invertible functions $f^{-1} \circ f^{-1}\circ k \circ f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$, is invertible. If $w$ is the inverse of $g \circ g$, then $w \circ g$ is a left inverse of $g$ (so $g$ is $1-1$) and $g\circ w$ is a right inverse of $g$ (so $g$ is onto). Hence, $g$ is invertible.